# Implement adapter pattern in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord, adapter

I just want to ask some opinion about my task. Currently, I'm refactoring our api codebase which handles both web and ios mobile. I refactored some models then the web handles it perfectly but then I got some concern with the mobile. In mobile we can update it same with the web but I still need to cater the old version. I don't know how to handle the versioning in the model. What I'm thinking know is to create adapter for the models that I refactored so whenever the request comes from old version I'll just use the adapted models. Is this possible? any ideas how I can handle this problem?

```
module ModelAdapter
   class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
     # CODE HERE
     ....
     ....
   end
end
```

Comment: Not able to answer your question properly but can hand you an adapter pattern [example](https://github.com/v-tsvid/design-patterns-in-ruby/tree/master/adapter)

Comment: Thanks @VAD. I came across a lot of blogs for adapter pattern but still I don't have any idea how to do adapter pattern in models.